# Rename Files in Powershell by moving string to right or left of character

Tags: powershell

I have a batch of files with the current format:

```
[filename]_[date].jpg
```

I wish to rename them to the following format:

```
[date]_[filename].jpg
```

To do this I created the following script:

```
GET-CHILDITEM .\*.jpg | WHERE-OBJECT {$_.NAME -MATCH '[A-Za-z]+?_[0-9]{6}.jpg'} | RENAME-ITEM -NEWNAME {[STRING]($_.NAME).SUBSTRING($_.BASENAME.LENGTH - 6, 6) + ($_.NAME).SUBSTRING(0,$_.INDEXOF("_"))+$_.EXTENSION} -WHATIF
```

I get an error saying [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'INDEXOF'

I know my problem is INDEXOF. I do not think I can use it in this way. So my question is what do I use?

On the same topic would the same method work in reverse, moving a string from the right to the left of "_"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually much easier than you expect if you add a `ForEach-Object` loop to your pipeline. Since you're already using the `-match` operator you can utilize the `$Matches` automatic variable like such:

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.jpg | Where{$_.Name -match '^([A-Za-z]+?)_(\d{6})\.jpg'} | ForEach{
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName {$Matches[2] + '_' + $Matches[1] + '.jpg'} -WhatIf 
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$x = '[filename]_[date].jpg' 
$a = $x.split('_.')
$y = ( $a[1], $a[0] ) -join '_' 
($y, $a[2] )  -join '.'
```